# Flask app on pythonanywhere, python JSON decode error

Tags: python, json, deployment, flask, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to replicate my app the runs on localhost, but on pythonanywhere.

I have a very basic API that provides a JSON response and it all works as expected on localhost:5000.

Moving the code to pythonanywhere, i get a `500 Internal Server Error`

The route is:

```
@app.route('/api/get_authors', methods = ['GET'])
def get_authors():
    authors = get_poi_authors()
    return jsonify(authors)
```

And the problem seems to come from a line in my getPoiAuthors code:

```
poiData = json.loads(getResult)['pois']
```

This works as expected on my machine, but not on pythonanywhere. I get a 'No JSON object could be decoded' Error. Could it problems with python versions? I run 2.7.6.

Comment: What is `getResult`?

Comment: Its a python dictionary

Comment: `json.loads` wants a string containing a JSON object that it can convert to a dictionary. If you already have a dictionary, all you should need is `poiData = getResult['pois']`.

Comment: If your app is calling its own API, is it possible that you've hard-coded `localhost` as the hostname to make api calls to?  that won't work on PythonAnywhere, you'd need your webapp name, eg username.pythonanywhere.com

Comment: I've checked and nowhere do i hard code and reference to 'localhost'. Not unless it defaults to it somewhere... In debug maybe?