# Reading json in pythonanywhere flask app

Tags: python, json, flask, pythonanywhere

First I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464539/flask-app-on-pythonanywhere-python-json-decode-error). My problem is I have a flask app running on pythonanywhere that reads info from a json file in the same directory on the server, and get the following error:
`Internal Server Error:The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.`.

I simplified the app down to:

```
from flask import Flask
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return 'Index'

@app.route('/courses')
def courses():
    with open('courses.json', 'r') as f:
        these_courses = json.load(f)
    return str(these_courses)
```

If I go to the index page I see index, as expected, but if I try to go to `/courses` then I get the error.The whole things runs fine on `localhost`, then with the same code I get an error on the server, so I know reading from the file works fine. This makes me think it might be a problem unique to json combined with pythonanywhere.

Edit: Perhaps a problem with the path name for `courses.json`, but it's in the same directory so I feel like it should be fine, just a thought

Comment: Most unlikely. Since the `index` method works, why not import `os` and have it print `os.getcwd()` to verify the current directory actually is what you think it is? Also, find out where the server error log is and look at that

Comment: I tried something similar to that just now, changed the path, and now it works, thanks! I put what I did as an answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was a pathname problem. I guess on files need to be routed from the root directory.

I ran:

```
def courses():
    my_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    json_file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, 'courses.json')
    return json_file_path
```

to find the path, then changed the function to:

```
def courses():
    with open('/home/username/path/to/file/courses.json', 'r') as f:
        these_courses = json.load(f)
    return str(these_courses)
```

and now it worked :D

Then to make a better version that doesn't break when you move the project I did it like this:

```
def courses():
    my_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    json_file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, 'courses.json')
    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
        these_courses = json.load(f)
    return str(these_courses)
```

Comment: That "better version" solved it for me (so that it works both locally and in PythonAnywhere with the same code).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative:

```
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path('courses.json').absolute()

these_courses = json.loads(path.read_text())
```