# Python anywhere don't see file

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

all. Today i wanted upload my small-forum on **pythonanywhere**. I debug some there mistakes, for example absence folder 'static' :). But now i cant delete one mistake.

for my forum i use a small database by file  `database.json`  but **pythonanywhere** doesn't see my file.

[i uploaded my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCEK1.jpg)

but i have bug.

```
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'database.json'
2022-08-21 14:47:48,879: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2051, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1501, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1485, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/Gsites2023/mysite/flask_app.py", line 58, in index
    with open("database.json", "r") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'database.json'`
```

please help me anywhere.

*P.S. i saved changes before test*

Comment: try using the full path shown via that webpage

Comment: 1) Sorry, my english so bed. 2) if you need my python code, say me(i think there problem in hosting)

Comment: problem is with hosting service

Comment: Sorry i dont understand you. Full name of my file is 'database.json', and this name i write in site

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the full path, in your case I think that would be

```
open("/home/Gsites2023/mysite/database.json", "r")
```

that is if the database is in the same directory as the main flask app script.

Answer (score 0):

For me [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32186419/5093220) solved it.
Essentially, you need to append the root from pythonanywhere to your file path, then it just works both locally and in pythonanywhere with the same code.

```
...
root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
with open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r+') as file:
    ...
```